# ScrollView с фиксированной картинкой

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

Пытаюсь сделать такой макет:

Фон должен быть фиксированной картинкой.

Если в нижнем EditText пусто - скролла нет.

При вводе текста в EditText - должен появляться скролл вниз.
Т.е. **EditText должен расти вниз**.

Перепробовал ряд вариантов макета - никак не могу добиться такого.

Как можно это реализовать ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скролиться должен весь экран или только EditText ?

Comment: @ШуткоАлександр скролиться должен весь экран, но бекграунд картинка фиксированная.  Суть в том, что EditText при добавлении текста должен расти вниз..